# Splitting field for $x^4-x^2-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Am i right to say that the splitting field for $x^4-x^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ which is of degree 4? i.e. $\{a+b\sqrt{2} + ci+di\sqrt{2} : a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the roots of $\;x^4-x^2-2=(x^2-2)(x^2+1)\;$ are $\;\pm\sqrt2\,,\,\,\pm i\;$ , the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Hi. I was just wondering if the number of roots in the polynomial is equal to the degree of the splitting field? thanks

Comment: @amiz9 Of course not. For example, $\;\pm\sqrt2\;$ both belong to the same extension $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\;$, and the same for $\;\pm i\;$ .

Comment: OK, thanks. So how would one calculate the degree of a splitting field ?

Comment: @amiz9 Using the field tower $\;\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\subset\Bbb Q(i)\;$ and the multiplicativity of degrees. For example, observe that $\;x^2+1\;$ **remains irreducible** over $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\;$ , since its roots are complex non-real and $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\;$ is a real field...